# Change each item of string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What I have

```
"path1/path2/path3"
```

what I want

```
"my_namespace:path1/my_namespace:path2/my_namespace:path3"
```

and I did:

```
a = "path1/path2/path3"
b = a.split("/").map{ |item| "my_namespace:"+ item}
puts b.join("/")
```

Of course, it works. But I'm curious if there is any other better way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a good use case for `String#gsub`:

```
a = "path1/path2/path3".gsub(%r{[^/]+/?}) { |m| "mynamespace:#{m}" }
p a #=> "mynamespace:path1/mynamespace:path2/mynamespace:path3"
```

Comment: In my example I used `path1...2...3`. But in the real app I don't use that pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I was much too literal minded there. While someone might be able to provide a better regexp, I think the above is now closer to what you want, I edited it.

Comment: It's fine. But it's hard to understand what how that regex in particular really works. Can you please explain?

Comment: I edited it again to remove the escaping, that probably clears it up a bit. But to be exact [^/] is "Not a /", + is "One or more", and then /? is "Zero or one slash".  So it basically matches an arbitrary amount of characters followed by a slash (or the end of the string).

Answer (score 2):

```
a.gsub(/(?<=^|\/)/, "my_namespace:")
# => "my_namespace:path1/my_namespace:path2/my_namespace:path3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant different namespaces for your paths. If so then you can use zip

```
"path1/path2/path3".split('/').zip(['namespace1','namespace2','namespace3']).
  map { |p,n| n + ':' + p }.join('/')

=> "namespace1:path1/namespace2:path2/namespace3:path3"
```